# $(document).ready(...) doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, express

I have the following ejs template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Emasc Editor</title>
        <style>
            .list{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javscript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('test');
    $("#setMembershipsButton").click(function(e){
        // send selected person and groups to server and create memberships
        data = {
            person: $('#person_list').val(),
            groups: $('#group_list').val()
        };
        $.post('/newConnections', data);
    });
    $("#person_list").change(function(){
        alert('test');
        // send selected person to server and retrieve memberships
        $.post('/getPersonGroups', { personID: $('#person_list').val() }, function(data, textStatus){
            $('#group_list option').removeAttr('selected');
            for(var i=0; i<data.ids.length; i++){
                $('#group_list option[value=' + data.ids[i] + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="list">
            <select id="person_list" size="<%= persons.length+1 %>">
                <% for( var i=0; i<persons.length; i++){ %>
                    <option value="<%= persons[i].id %>"><%= persons[i].name %></option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
            <form method="post" action="/newPerson">
                <input type="text" name="user[name]" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="list">
            <select id="group_list" multiple size="<%= groups.length+1 %>">
                <% for( var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){ %>
                    <option value="<%= groups[i].id %>"><%= groups[i].name %></option>
                <% } %>
            </select>
            <form method="post" action="/newGroup">
                <input type="text" name="group[name]" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <input id="setMembershipsButton" type="button" value="Set Memberships"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the first alert('test') never gets called. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the JS console?

Comment: Verify the location of /js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: I am able to use $ in the chrome console, leading me to think that jquery is included. Also Chrome Resources says it's there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script type is invalid:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script):

> **type**
>   This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript. If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.

However, if the type is not recognized by the browser, the block is ignored.  It's best to leave out the `type` attribute entirely to avoid mistyping it.

Comment: Or better yet, remove it completely.